# What is the PowerShell equivalent of the Unix shell `export` command?

Tags: powershell, shell

What is the equivalent in PowerShell of:

```
export pwtst=777; bash -c 'echo xxx${pwtst}xxx'
```

?

I want to expose the variables set in PowerShell to traditional Unix shells.

When I run this is in `zsh`, for example, I get:

```
xxx777xxx
```

but in PowerShell

```
export $pwtst=777; bash -c 'echo xxx${pwtst}xxx'
```

results in

```
export: The term 'export' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I tried

```
$global:pwtst='777'; bash -c 'echo xxx${pwtst}xxx'
```

but that returns

```
xxxxxx
```

and I tried

```
$global:pwtst=777; Export-ModuleMember -Variable pwtst; bash -c 'echo xxx${pwtst}xxx'
```

which resulted in

```
Export-ModuleMember: The Export-ModuleMember cmdlet can only be called from inside a module.
```

---

PS- I am trying to pass values to sub shells, this is just a test for me. I *know* I could do `bash -c "echo xxx${pwtst}xxx"` but then it'll be PowerShell doing the variable substitution and not the sub shell (ie Bash). My use case is porting over an existing collection of shell scripts to PowerShell since it's more cross-platform friendly and top-down is easier than bottom up because it means means the difficult niche scripts can be left for last.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `env:` scope or drive:

```
$env:pwtst='777'; bash -c 'echo xxx${pwtst}xxx'   

xxx777xxx
```

Using env: as a drive example:

```
set-content env:foo 'hi'; bash -c 'echo $foo'                    

hi
```

Comment: sorry what is `drive:`?

Comment: @sled You can treat env: as a drive as well, `get-childitem env:`.  `get-psdrive` shows all the drives.

Comment: echo $env:pwtst